# Django migration with python3.6 ERROR:root:code for hash sha3_224 was not found

Tags: django, migration, models, python-3.6

Hello I read [Django tutorials](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/series/2017/09/11/a-complete-beginners-guide-to-django-part-2.html#figure-4) and I have an error related to specific `sha3_224` hash function during the migration process. How to solve this problem? Thank you.

```
(venv) linuxoid@linuxoid-ThinkPad-L540:~/myprojects/myproject$ python manage.py makemigrations
ERROR:root:code for hash sha3_224 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/linuxoid/myprojects/venv/lib/python3.6/hashlib.py", line 121, in __get_openssl_constructor
    f = getattr(_hashlib, 'openssl_' + name)
AttributeError: module '_hashlib' has no attribute 'openssl_sha3_224'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/linuxoid/myprojects/venv/lib/python3.6/hashlib.py", line 243, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/home/linuxoid/myprojects/venv/lib/python3.6/hashlib.py", line 128, in __get_openssl_constructor
    return __get_builtin_constructor(name)
  File "/home/linuxoid/myprojects/venv/lib/python3.6/hashlib.py", line 113, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha3_224
ERROR:root:code for hash sha3_256 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/linuxoid/myprojects/venv/lib/python3.6/hashlib.py", line 121, in __get_openssl_constructor
    f = getattr(_hashlib, 'openssl_' + name)
AttributeError: module '_hashlib' has no attribute 'openssl_sha3_256'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/linuxoid/myprojects/venv/lib/python3.6/hashlib.py", line 243, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/home/linuxoid/myprojects/venv/lib/python3.6/hashlib.py", line 128, in __get_openssl_constructor
    return __get_builtin_constructor(name)
  File "/home/linuxoid/myprojects/venv/lib/python3.6/hashlib.py", line 113, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha3_256
ERROR:root:code for hash sha3_384 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/linuxoid/myprojects/venv/lib/python3.6/hashlib.py", line 121, in __get_openssl_constructor
    f = getattr(_hashlib, 'openssl_' + name)
AttributeError: module '_hashlib' has no attribute 'openssl_sha3_384'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/linuxoid/myprojects/venv/lib/python3.6/hashlib.py", line 243, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/home/linuxoid/myprojects/venv/lib/python3.6/hashlib.py", line 128, in __get_openssl_constructor
    return __get_builtin_constructor(name)
  File "/home/linuxoid/myprojects/venv/lib/python3.6/hashlib.py", line 113, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha3_384
ERROR:root:code for hash sha3_512 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/linuxoid/myprojects/venv/lib/python3.6/hashlib.py", line 121, in __get_openssl_constructor
    f = getattr(_hashlib, 'openssl_' + name)
AttributeError: module '_hashlib' has no attribute 'openssl_sha3_512'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/linuxoid/myprojects/venv/lib/python3.6/hashlib.py", line 243, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/home/linuxoid/myprojects/venv/lib/python3.6/hashlib.py", line 128, in __get_openssl_constructor
    return __get_builtin_constructor(name)
  File "/home/linuxoid/myprojects/venv/lib/python3.6/hashlib.py", line 113, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha3_512
ERROR:root:code for hash shake_128 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/linuxoid/myprojects/venv/lib/python3.6/hashlib.py", line 121, in __get_openssl_constructor
    f = getattr(_hashlib, 'openssl_' + name)
AttributeError: module '_hashlib' has no attribute 'openssl_shake_128'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/linuxoid/myprojects/venv/lib/python3.6/hashlib.py", line 243, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/home/linuxoid/myprojects/venv/lib/python3.6/hashlib.py", line 128, in __get_openssl_constructor
    return __get_builtin_constructor(name)
  File "/home/linuxoid/myprojects/venv/lib/python3.6/hashlib.py", line 113, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type shake_128
ERROR:root:code for hash shake_256 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/linuxoid/myprojects/venv/lib/python3.6/hashlib.py", line 121, in __get_openssl_constructor
    f = getattr(_hashlib, 'openssl_' + name)
AttributeError: module '_hashlib' has no attribute 'openssl_shake_256'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/linuxoid/myprojects/venv/lib/python3.6/hashlib.py", line 243, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/home/linuxoid/myprojects/venv/lib/python3.6/hashlib.py", line 128, in __get_openssl_constructor
    return __get_builtin_constructor(name)
  File "/home/linuxoid/myprojects/venv/lib/python3.6/hashlib.py", line 113, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type shake_256
No changes detected
```

Comment: Im getting roughly this stack trace when trying to use django channels, a downgrade nor recreating the virtual env cleared this up. Can someone speak to where hashlib is actually getting this encodings, and where django is trying to use them? why does downgrading or building a new venv help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solved my issue:

```
cd /usr/bin
sudo cp python3.6 python3
```

Previously I had 3.6.2, after doing `apt-upgrade` the system was broken.

Answer (score 14):

Check if your python has been updated recently. The venv might be pointing to the old one, recreating venv fixed it for us.

Running `mkvirtualenv venv` or `virtualenv venv` (depending on how you created it in the first place) should also work while keeping the installed packages.

Answer (score 4):

**!Mind it is really hot fix!**

This issue appears in new version of python - 3.6.3.

Downgrade to 3.6.2 helped me

Here is legacy PPA: https://launchpad.net/~fkrull/+archive/ubuntu/deadsnakes/+index?batch=75&direction=backwards&start=75

Commands for further actions of **downgrading** python:

`sudo apt install libpython3.6-minimal=3.6.2-1+xenial1
sudo apt install python3.6-minimal=3.6.2-1+xenial1
sudo apt install python3.6-stdlib=3.6.2-1+xenial1
sudo apt install python3.6=3.6.2-1+xenial1`

Comment: Also, collegues said virtualenv reinitilizing solved the problem because of old common python libraries used there

Comment: This happened to me after upgrading to 3.6.3
Recreating virtualenv with 3.6.3 solved the issue

Comment: @tista3 AWESOME. Thanks. The exact same thing happened to me. I ran some updates (not realizing that python went from 3.6.2 to 3.6.3). You should write an answer since this was more explicitly the solution for me.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me after upgrading to 3.6.3 Try create new virtualenv with Python 3.6.3 or newer. This solved the problem for me.