# Django Ubuntu 16.04 "unsupported hash type"

Tags: python, django, ubuntu-16.04, hashlib

I've deployed a web app to an Ubuntu 16.04 VM. I implemented the standard Django login by the books. Everything is working properly on my production environment (OS X); however, when I attempt to login I receive the error

> ExceptionValue: unsupported hash type

```
Ubuntu is running python 3.5.2

OS X is running python 3.6.1
```

Both are running Django Version 1.11.6

My requirements.txt

```
blessings==1.6
bpython==0.16
certifi==2017.7.27.1
chardet==3.0.4
curtsies==0.2.11
Django==1.11.6
django-extensions==1.9.6
geopy==1.11.0
greenlet==0.4.12
idna==2.6
psycopg2==2.7.3.2
Pygments==2.2.0
pytz==2017.2
requests==2.18.4
six==1.11.0
urllib3==1.22
wcwidth==0.1.7
```

I am using a virtual environment to run this project.

The traceback path is as follows,

Traceback:

> File
>   "/home/user_name/proj_folder/my_venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py"
>   in inner
>     41.             response = get_response(request)
>
> File
>   "/home/user_name/proj_folder/my_venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py"
>   in _get_response
>     187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
>
> File
>   "/home/user_name/proj_folder/my_venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py"
>   in _get_response
>     185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
>
> File
>   "/home/user_name/proj_folder/my_venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/views.py"
>   in inner
>     54.         return func(*args, **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "/home/user_name/proj_folder/my_venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/views.py"
>   in login
>     150.     )(request)
>
> File
>   "/home/user_name/proj_folder/my_venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py"
>   in view
>     68.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "/home/user_name/proj_folder/my_venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py"
>   in _wrapper
>     67.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "/home/user_name/proj_folder/my_venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/decorators/debug.py"
>   in sensitive_post_parameters_wrapper
>     76.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "/home/user_name/proj_folder/my_venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py"
>   in bound_func
>     63.                 return func.**get**(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)
>
> File
>   "/home/user_name/proj_folder/my_venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py"
>   in _wrapper
>     67.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "/home/user_name/proj_folder/my_venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py"
>   in _wrapped_view
>     149.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "/home/user_name/proj_folder/my_venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py"
>   in bound_func
>     63.                 return func.**get**(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)
>
> File
>   "/home/user_name/proj_folder/my_venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py"
>   in _wrapper
>     67.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "/home/user_name/proj_folder/my_venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py"
>   in _wrapped_view_func
>     57.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "/home/user_name/proj_folder/my_venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py"
>   in bound_func
>     63.                 return func.**get**(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)
>
> File
>   "/home/user_name/proj_folder/my_venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/views.py"
>   in dispatch
>     90.         return super(LoginView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "/home/user_name/proj_folder/my_venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py"
>   in dispatch
>     88.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "/home/user_name/proj_folder/my_venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py"
>   in post
>     182.         if form.is_valid():
>
> File
>   "/home/user_name/proj_folder/my_venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py"
>   in is_valid
>     183.         return self.is_bound and not self.errors
>
> File
>   "/home/user_name/proj_folder/my_venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py"
>   in errors
>     175.             self.full_clean()
>
> File
>   "/home/user_name/proj_folder/my_venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py"
>   in full_clean
>     385.         self._clean_form()
>
> File
>   "/home/user_name/proj_folder/my_venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py"
>   in _clean_form
>     412.             cleaned_data = self.clean()
>
> File
>   "/home/user_name/proj_folder/my_venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/forms.py"
>   in clean
>     187.             self.user_cache = authenticate(self.request, username=username, password=password)
>
> File
>   "/home/user_name/proj_folder/my_venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/**init**.py"
>   in authenticate
>     70.             user = _authenticate_with_backend(backend, backend_path, request, credentials)
>
> File
>   "/home/user_name/proj_folder/my_venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/**init**.py"
>   in _authenticate_with_backend
>     115.     return backend.authenticate(*args, **credentials)
>
> File
>   "/home/user_name/proj_folder/my_venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/backends.py"
>   in authenticate
>     24.             if user.check_password(password) and self.user_can_authenticate(user):
>
> File
>   "/home/user_name/proj_folder/my_venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py"
>   in check_password
>     118.         return check_password(raw_password, self.password, setter)
>
> File
>   "/home/user_name/proj_folder/my_venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/hashers.py"
>   in check_password
>     52.     is_correct = hasher.verify(password, encoded)
>
> File
>   "/home/user_name/proj_folder/my_venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/hashers.py"
>   in verify
>     265.         encoded_2 = self.encode(password, salt, int(iterations))
>
> File
>   "/home/user_name/proj_folder/my_venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/hashers.py"
>   in encode
>     258.         hash = pbkdf2(password, salt, iterations, digest=self.digest)
>
> File
>   "/home/user_name/proj_folder/my_venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/crypto.py"
>   in pbkdf2
>     140.             digest().name, password, salt, iterations, dklen)
>
> Exception Type: ValueError at /login/ Exception Value: unsupported
>   hash type

The traceback is entirely within my venv folder. The final error is shown below. Lines 133-146 of

> /home/user_name/proj_folder/my_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/crypto.py
>   in pbkdf2

```
        if digest is None:
            digest = hashlib.sha256
        if not dklen:
            dklen = None
        password = force_bytes(password)
        salt = force_bytes(salt)
        return hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac(
            digest().name, password, salt, iterations, dklen) ...
else:
    def pbkdf2(password, salt, iterations, dklen=0, digest=None):
        """
        Implements PBKDF2 as defined in RFC 2898, section 5.2
        HMAC+SHA256 is used as the default pseudo random function.
```

The final exception is thrown at `digest().name, password, salt, iterations, dklen)`

With Local Vars:

```
digest      <built-in function openssl_sha256>
dklen       None
iterations  36000
password    b'mypassword'
salt        b'saltshownhere'
```

I've seen similar questions relating to Solaris 10 where there may have been a problem with SSL installation/version. OpenSSL is installed on both machines. Although they are different versions.

```
Ubuntu - OpenSSL 1.0.2g

OS - OpenSSL 0.9.8zh
```

I am able to successfully run my application by removing the login requirement. I'd like to have a better understanding of what is going on here. Could this be a version error between my development and production environment caused by python or OpenSSL?

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46631071/django-migration-with-python3-6-errorrootcode-for-hash-sha3-224-was-not-found

Comment: Seems like there's somthing wrong with your `hashlib`, which is in the standard library. Try installing python 3.6 on the ubuntu VM as well.

Comment: My guess is that the built in `openssl_sha256` doesn't have a `name` property on this version of ubuntu / python. The error message indicates this, since it should usually say **unsupported hash type sha256**, but in your case, there's no name there. 

https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/hashlib.html#hashlib.hash.name

Comment: @HåkenLid I'm having trouble installing Python3.6 and getting it to work with my venv. I see that there is a way to add an activate_this script and point to a different binary, but I can't get that to work. I also installed the packages globally, but they are not accessible to the python3.6 path.