# command pip list in venv throws "code for hash sha3_224 was not found" error

Tags: python-3.x, pip, virtualenvwrapper

I had a working environment using virtualwrapper, pip9, python3.6 and Ubuntu17.04. Since several libs for Python cannot be updated using 17.04 since 1st of February, I upgraded to Ubuntu17.10.

Command "workon" still returns the correct virtualenvironments.
Command "workon venv" correctly takes me to the desired venv. There I enter command "pip list" to see the libs I had installed with pip and this will throw the error.

```
(venv)$ pip list
ERROR:root:code for hash sha3_224 was not found.
...
```

In fact this will give me the same error message as can be found at [Django migration with Python3.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46631071/django-migration-with-python3-6-errorrootcode-for-hash-sha3-224-was-not-found)

The there suggested solution to recreate the virtualenv with mkvirtual venv might be correct, but I would appreciate if someone could affirm this or suggest a better way to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I simply created a new venv using mkvirtualenv venv_new and copied the old venv into the new one. That huge error message made me overly cautious.